# MATLAB eig(A,B) of a positive semi-definite matrix pair (A,B) gives complex eigenvalues

Tags: matlab, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A and B both are 151 by 151 psd matrices, I want to solve the generalized eigenvalue proplem

A * v = Lambda * B * v

when using MATLAB function eig()

[V,D] = eig(A,B)

I get complex numbers in both V and D.Why did this happen and is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: you can get another matrix  $C$ which is equal  $C=A*B^{-1}$ and solve $C*v=\lambda*v$

Comment: I've already tried that but the result is no good.

Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
         Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 5.557341e-019.